# Difference command giving inconsistent attribute results for QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am attempting to isolate datasets from various layers that I've completed Union commands on previously.

The data is currently set up that EX-3 is the largest area. EX-2 is a smaller dataset within EX-3. And EX-1 is a smaller dataset wholly within EX-2 (and be default EX-3).

My design situation changed and I've determined that instead of having large datasets, I just need the difference between each dataset now.

So after some looking through the different Geoprocessing tools options, I determined that the Difference command would be best. I ran Difference so that my input layer was the full EX-2 dataset and my difference layer was the full EX-1 dataset.

The output that was provided visually included only the portions of EX-2 which were beyond EX-1's limit; furthermore, all attributes were for the net difference of the two datasets. Overall, it worked perfectly.

[image: EX-2 Visual][image: EX-2 Attributes]

The issue is occurring when I attempt to do the same thing for the for the EX-3 portions. My input layer is the full EX-3 dataset and the difference layer is the full EX-2 dataset. This results in an output which *looks* correct visually, but the attributes table is including a ton of data that's no longer applicable.

[image: EX-3 Visual][image: EX-3 Attributes]

If it's relevant, I'm working on QGIS version 3.2.3-Bonn.

EDIT: One thing that I noticed is that when I use the Zoom to Layer command on the EX-3 Difference layer, it zooms me out to show everything in the project. I suspect this is related to the issue, but I'm not sure why it's happening.

The excess data in the attributes table appears to be coming from the original, larger dataset. It's not clear why this data is coming as it seems that the Difference command should cut it out entirely as what occurred with the EX-2 dataset.

Comment: As a potential note for meta, I've tried uploading images of my issue a few times and I keep getting a server error.

Comment: Could you upload those screenshots externally and link them to your question, please?

Comment: @Erik server error finally resolved, so I've uploaded the images.

Comment: It's possible your EX-3 layer has some problematic geometry that results in unexpected results from the Difference tool. Have you checked the EX-3 layer geometry (eg using check validity or fix geometry tools)